# Tree node counter algorithm: please explain this recursion step by step

Tags: python, recursion, tree

Given the following tree:

```
#                     'Mobs'
#             /          |           \
#     'NPC'          'Enemies'         'Heroes'
#     /           /       |      \            \
# 'Andrew'    'Slime'  'Goblin'  'Dragon'      'Human'
#                                     \
#                                     'Wyrm'

tree = ('Mobs', [('NPC', [('Andew', [])]), ('Enemies', [('Slime', []), ('Goblin', []), ('Dragon', [('Wyrm', [])])]), ('Heroes', [('Human', [])])])
```

Each node is a tuple, composed of a string at [0] and a list of possible children at [1].
The following function returns the count successfully:

```
def how_many(node):
    count = 1                                   
    for i in node[1]:                           
        count = count + how_many(i)             
    return count
```

I am trying to understand what it does exactly. Somebody explained me that I needed to picture myself "Stacks" to understand how recursion work. Let me try to phrase what I understood:
Since the program does not have all the information as of the moment it calls itself for the first time, it is powerful enough to put all the operations on hold, stack them so that the order they will be executed in is preserved, goes on until it reaches the base case – which is in our function when the tree node does not have children – and yields the right stacked up value in our count variable so that it can return it when the loop is complete.

Am I right?
I need someone to explain in words what the function does step by step if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can think of boxes. 
Let's say we want to count boxes.

1. You have a big box Mobs. You have one box `count = 1` Start of your recursion.
2. You open the box. You see three small boxes (NPC, Enemies, Heroes). `for i in node[1]`
3. You take the first box (NPC) and ask how many boxes do I have in NPC. `count = count + how_many(i)`.
4. You have 1 Box (NPC) `count = 1`
5. You open the box and see a smaller box (Andrew) `for i in node[1]`.
6. You take the box again and ask how many boxes do I have in Andrew. `count = count + how_many(i)`
7. You have 1 Box (Andrew). `count = 1`
8. You open the box and don't see any smaller box. You don't enter the for loop `for i in node[1]`
9. You return count which is 1.

10 You come back to the Box before (NPC) you get 1 back from `how_many(i)` (from Andrew) and have 1 form NPC. 1 + 1 = 2

11 There are no other boxes in NPC therefore you exit the for loop and return count which is 2.

12. You are back in your first box (Mob). You get 2 back and have 1 from the Mob box. `1 + 2 = 3`.
13. You are still in the for loop and check the next box (Enemies).
14. You do the same in short: Enemies will return 5 (Enemies, Slime, Goblin, Dragon, Wyrm). You count `3 + 5 = 8`.
15. The last box is still there (Heroes)
16. Do the same in short: Heroes will return 2 (Heroes, Human) and you count `8 + 2 = 10`.
17. The last return is `count = 10`

**result = 10**

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough and complete answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler use case for recursion : Factorial function `n! = n * (n-1) *... * 2 * 1`

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        result = 1
    else: result = n * factorial(n-1)
    return result

print(factorial(2))
```

What happens here ?

- `factorial(2)` is called. It goes in the `else` condition and then waits for `factorial(1)` result
- `factorial(1)` is called. It goes in the `else` condition and then waits for `factorial(0)` result
- `factorial(0)` is called. It goes in the `if` condition this time. The result **1** is returned.
- we go back in the function `factorial(1)` where we can solve the line `result = n * factorial(n-1)`. The result 1*1 = 1 is returned.
- we finally go back in the function `factorial(2)` where we can solve the line `result = n * factorial(n-1)`. The result 1*1*2 = 2 is returned.
- it prints **2**